# Loading Google Maps API v3 in the same page via $.ajax()

Tags: ajax, dom, google-maps-api-3, asynchronous

I've already spent a whole day trying to understand the concept of loading Google Maps API specifically by the $.ajax() method, but no success. I am quite new in the javascript language, and I would like someone to definitely explain to me those DOM listener events issues.

So basically I have an index.php with a hidden div, where by clicking on the content div the jQuery forces the hidden div to show up and loads inside it the map.php (that is the Google Maps drawing Circle), but just the modal box hidden div shows up with nothing inside!! I am assured that the $.ajax() is working because if I type 'foo' inside the map.php,the 'foo' shows up with the modal box inside it, proving that the ajax is really loading the map.php inside the modal box.

When I load the map.php alone, it works fine. And when I force inside the map.php to alert the center of the circles it works fine, proving that the compiler is processing the google maps api library. But I am putting the google api script source inside both php in the index and in tha map.php

So Please explain to me:

- If I'am loading the GMaps API by $.ajax() where do I need to put the (script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false)
  inside the index.php or inside the map.php? And why?
- If the google maps script source is in the head of the map.php, and I am loading it directly form the browser, it is clear that all the map is generated by the javascript code, so why do I need to call the addDomListener function at the end of the code? What is the order that the compiler process the code? Does it doesn't understand all the map javascript code at the begining? does it need to be triggered by de DOM window onload event to precess all the javascript block?Why without the addDomListener it doesn't work?
- What is the DOM window onload event? Do I have one of it for the index.php and when I load the map.php via ajax do I have another DOM window onlaod event? How that DOM window onload behave when I am using the $.ajax() method?
- And in which order the compiler process the block code below? If I have the function initialize ABOVE the function loadScript why the compiler looks first fot the lodScript AND THEN call is callback, the initizalize function?

Can anyone elucidate those four questions please?

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
      'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

Here is the index.php

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.content').click(function(){

        //jQuery code that shows the hidden div 'modal_box'

        $.ajax({
           url       : 'map.php',

           dataType  : 'html',

           success : function(return){  $(".modal_box").html(return); }
        });

    });



 </script>
    <head>
    <title>Index</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div class='content'>Click Here</div>
       <div class='modal_box'><div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And in the map.php I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Circles</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>

var citymap = {};
citymap['chicago'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878113, -87.629798),
  population: 2842518
};
citymap['newyork'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714352, -74.005973),
  population: 8143197
};
citymap['losangeles'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243684),
  population: 3844829
};
var cityCircle;

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

 for (var city in citymap) {
    var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: citymap[city].population / 20
    };

    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Four questions, in one?

Comment: why not make the `map.php` file return json of your map data and then have your `index.php` process the data to create the map instead?  Also, i've never tried to load in full html page as html content - you would typically need to use an iframe for stuff like that.